# Create polygon from set of points

Tags: java, javafx, polygon

I have a list of two dimensional points. I want to draw a shape on a JavaFX canvas. Therefore, I need to create a polygon from my list of points. How do I do that?

The problem is, my points do not define a outer bound but look more like a cloud. For creating the shape, I thus need to know which points are needed.
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxt6q.png%20This%20image) shows what I want to achieve, although the shapes don't have to be that perfect.

Edit: Gave more detail to explain what the main problem is

Comment: That's not the problem. I edited the question to describe my problem better

Comment: Looks like you need to calculate an approximate a shape based on a cloud of data points. Sounds more like a math problem to me than a programming problem. I suggest you ask this over on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

How the Documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) says:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
    0.0, 0.0,
    20.0, 10.0,
    10.0, 20.0 });
```

So, after your edit: This is a kind of cluster analysis. Look here for a good algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis